# Crop icon image so background is equal to the perimeter of icon

Tags: css

[image: fire icons that I want to crop]

How can I crop this image so the background only extends to the edge of the icon? I would like to color each icon like the image I provided, but I need to remove the square background and have only the space inside the icon change color, can someone help me with this?

Here is the jsx for the icon component

```
import React from 'react';
import fireIconImage from '../images/fireIcon.png';

export default function FireIcon(props) {
    return (
        <img
            onClick={props.onClick}
            onMouseLeave={props.onMouseLeave}
            onMouseOver={props.onMouseOver}
            className={props.className}
            src={fireIconImage}
            alt="fire icon"
            id={props.id}
        ></img>
    )
}
```

Here is the jsx for the parent component that holds the icons

```
import React from 'react'
import fireIconImage from '../images/fireIcon.png'
import FireIcon from './FireIcon'

export default function BlogPostForm () {
    const [formState, setFormState] = React.useState({ flaire: '', title: '', text: ''});
    const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = React.useState();
    const [isLit, setIsLit] = React.useState();

    function changeFlaire(event) {
        const selectedFlaire = event.target.value;
        setFormState( {...formState, flaire: selectedFlaire });
    }

    function changeTitle(event) {
        const title = event.target.value;
        setFormState( {...formState, title: title });
    }

    function changeText(event) {
        const text = event.target.value;
        setFormState( {...formState, text: text });
    }

    function handleMouseOver(e) {
        setIsHovered(e.target.id);
    }

    function handleMouseLeave(e) {
        setIsHovered();
    }

    function handleFireIconClick(e) {
        setIsLit(e.target.id);
    }

    function handleFireIconClass(fireLevel) {
        const classNames = ['fireIcon']
            classNames.push(`fireIcon${fireLevel}`)
            if (isHovered >= fireLevel) {
                classNames.push('isHeld')
            }
            if (isLit >= fireLevel) {
                classNames.push('isLit')
            }
            console.log(classNames)
        return classNames.join(' ');
        
    }


    const fireIconsArray = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        fireIconsArray.push(
            <FireIcon 
                onClick={handleFireIconClick}
                onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
                onMouseOver={handleMouseOver}
                className={handleFireIconClass(i+1)}
                src={fireIconImage}
                alt="fire icon"
                id={i+1}
            />
        )
    }

    console.log(fireIconsArray);
    
    return (
        <form className="postForm">
            <h1 className="postFormHeader">Create a blog post!</h1>        
                <select
                    required
                    className="flaireSelect" 
                    value={formState.flaire}
                    onChange={changeFlaire}>
                        <option disabled={true} value="">Choose a flaire</option>
                        <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
                        <option value="CSS">CSS</option>
                        <option value="HTML">HTML</option>
                        <option value="REACT">REACT</option>
                        <option value="BACKEND">BACKEND</option>
                </select>
                <input
                    value={formState.title}
                    onChange={changeTitle}
                    className="titleBox"
                    placeholder="title"
                    type="text"
                    id="title"
                    name="title"
                />
                <textarea
                    value={formState.text}
                    onChange={changeText}
                    className="textBox"
                    placeholder="text"
                    type="text"
                    id="blogPost"
                    name="blogPost"
                />
                <div className="fireIconContainer">
                    {fireIconsArray}
                </div>  
                <div className="blogPostFormButtonContainer">
                    <button className="blogPostSubmit" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
                    <button className="blogPostCancel" type="submit">CANCEL</button>
                </div>
        </form>
    )
}
```

Here is the css

```
/*blogPostForm */
.postForm {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  color: white;
  background-color: var(--color2);
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 750px;

  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "flaire"
    "title"
    "post"
    "buttons";
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.postFormHeader {
  justify-self: center;
}

.flaireSelect {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  justify-self: center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
}

select:invalid {
  color: grey;
}

.titleBox {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.textBox {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  resize: vertical;
}

.fireIconContainer {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.fireIcon {
  color: white;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.fireIcon1.isLit {
  background-color: #ffd000;
}

.fireIcon2.isLit {
  background-color: rgb(255, 136, 0);
}

.fireIcon3.isLit {
  background-color: hsl(22, 100%, 50%);
}

.fireIcon4.isLit {
  background-color: rgb(255, 51, 0);
}

.fireIcon5.isLit {
  background-color: rgb(187, 26, 4);
}

.isHeld {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.blogPostFormButtonContainer {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.blogPostSubmit {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  width: 35%;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 35px;
}

.blogPostCancel {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  width: 35%;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 35px;
}
```

Comment: can we please see the code you have written, so we can help fixing it.

Comment: @UmairFarooq I added the code, sorry about that

Comment: ok did that @Sean

Comment: Sharing React code makes it difficult for people to reproduce what you're looking at. Instead, just share the rendered HTML and CSS in a StackSnippet.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing something like that with `svg` & not `png`.
I made a CSS animation for demo purpose.

here I am changing colors of the fire every one second with `fill` property on the `svg`.
i hope this is not confusing...

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

svg {
  width: 100px;
}

.st0 {
  fill-rule: evenodd;
  clip-rule: evenodd;
  fill: #ffd100;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  animation: firestate 5s infinite;
}

.st1 {
  fill-rule: evenodd;
  clip-rule: evenodd;
  fill: #ffd100;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  animation: firestate 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes firestate {
  25% {
    fill: #ff8800;
  }
  50% {
    fill: #ff5e00;
  }
  75% {
    fill: #ff3200;
  }
  100% {
    fill: #bb1a04;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 92.27 122.88" style="enable-background:new 0 0 92.27 122.88" xml:space="preserve">
        <g>
            <path class="st0"
                d="M18.61,54.89C15.7,28.8,30.94,10.45,59.52,0C42.02,22.71,74.44,47.31,76.23,70.89 c4.19-7.15,6.57-16.69,7.04-29.45c21.43,33.62,3.66,88.57-43.5,80.67c-4.33-0.72-8.5-2.09-12.3-4.13C10.27,108.8,0,88.79,0,69.68 C0,57.5,5.21,46.63,11.95,37.99C12.85,46.45,14.77,52.76,18.61,54.89L18.61,54.89z" />
            <path class="st1"
                d="M33.87,92.58c-4.86-12.55-4.19-32.82,9.42-39.93c0.1,23.3,23.05,26.27,18.8,51.14 c3.92-4.44,5.9-11.54,6.25-17.15c6.22,14.24,1.34,25.63-7.53,31.43c-26.97,17.64-50.19-18.12-34.75-37.72 C26.53,84.73,31.89,91.49,33.87,92.58L33.87,92.58z" />
        </g>
    </svg>
</body>
```